How can I pin my app to the Windows Taskbar using Delphi code?
I'm writing an app where I'd like to provide users with the option to pin it to the Windows Taskbar programmatically. Is there a way to achieve this?
I've searched online, but the information seems to be scattered, outdated, or not related to Delphi. Can someone guide me on how to accomplish this task?
I have an FMX app, but I can just wrap the code in a Windows compiler directive? So code for VCL or FMX is fine.

If the user wants to pin your app to his or her taskbar, they can do that themselves.

Here’s how Microsoft says you can do it. (Doing this with Delphi is not something I can answer ATM. Sorry.)

The user literally right clicks the task bar button and selects pin. It beggars belief that people consider this insufficient.

The answer to your question is:  you cannot pin your app to the Windows taskbar. There is an api to ASK THE USER if they would like to pin your app to the taskbar--which is not the same thing. There is no public API available which allows apps to pin themselves programmatically to the Taskbar (or the Start Menu).  Pinning is strictly a user-controlled action.

@IanBoyd wow, way to quote my answer in a comment

@RemyLebeau I know; i wanted to re-inforce to everyone that your answer (which had -1) votes when i got to it is the correct answer.

There is no public API available which allows an app to directly pin itself programmatically to the Taskbar.  Pinning is strictly a user-controlled action.
But, there is a public API available which allows an app to ask the user to pin the app to the Taskbar on the app's behalf. Details are on Microsoft's site:
Pin your app to the taskbar
That being said, there are a number of requirements before you can use this feature. For instance, you have to register to get an unlock code from Microsoft first to use the API. And then you have to make sure your app is running in the foreground, and use the APIs to query if the Taskbar is available, if it allows pinning, and if your app is not already pinned, before you can then ask the user to pin your app.

As mentioned by Remy, there is no public API available, so you have to implement by yourself.
However, on new Windows updates, Windows 11 now asks the user permission for the application to be pinned using a notification prompt, which is fair.
Here is how I did for some experiments, this pins and unpins to the taskbar of Windows 10/11, but on new Windows 11 updates, it won't bypass the confirmation prompt, as this was planned for Windows in order not to abuse and let all applications to indiscriminately pin without user's permission.
unit TaskbarPinner;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  ShlObj, ActiveX, ShellApi, ComObj, RegChangeThread, DWMApi;

const
  SID_IShellDispatch6        = '{286e6f1b-7113-4355-9562-96b7e9d64c54}';
  IID_IShellDispatch5: TGUID = SID_IShellDispatch6;


const
  CLSID_TaskbandPin: TGUID = '{90AA3A4E-1CBA-4233-B8BB-535773D48449}';
  CLSID_TrayNotify: TGUID  = '{25DEAD04-1EAC-4911-9E3A-AD0A4AB560FD}';

  IID_IFlexibleTaskbarPinnedList: TGUID = '{60274FA2-611F-4B8A-A293-F27BF103D148}';
  IID_IUnknown: TGUID = '{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
  IID_IFlexibleTaskbarPinnedList0: TGUID = '{53d51c3c-d7e0-4fec-b4c6-33b4f8a41c64}';
  IID_IFlexibleTaskbarPinnedList1: TGUID = '{60274FA2-611F-4B8A-A293-F27BF103D148}';
  IID_IFlexibleTaskbarPinnedList2: TGUID = '{BBD20037-BC0E-42F1-913F-E2936BB0EA0C}';
  IID_IFlexibleTaskbarPinnedList3: TGUID = '{C3C6EB6D-C837-4EAE-B172-5FEC52A2A4FD}';
  IID_IPinnedList3: TGUID = '{0DD79AE2-D156-45D4-9EEB-3B549769E940}';
  SID_ITrayNotify = '{FB852B2C-6BAD-4605-9551-F15F87830935}';
  IID_ITrayNotify: TGUID = '{FB852B2C-6BAD-4605-9551-F15F87830935}';
  SID_INotificationCB = '{D782CCBA-AFB0-43F1-94DB-FDA3779EACCB}';
  IID_INotificationCB: TGUID = '{D782CCBA-AFB0-43F1-94DB-FDA3779EACCB}';

type
  PLMC =(PLMC_EXPLORER = 4);

  IFlexibleTaskbarPinnedList = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{60274FA2-611F-4B8A-A293-F27BF103D148}']
//    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
//    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
//    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
    function EnumObjects(var p2: IEnumFullIDList): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPinnableinfo: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsPinnable: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Resolve: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function LeaveFolder: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetChangeCount: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsPinned: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPinnedItem: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetAppIDForPinnedItem: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ItemChangeNotify: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UpdateForRemovedItemsAsNecessary: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function PinShellLink: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPinnedItemForAppID: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ApplyPrependDefaultTaskbarLayour: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ApplyInPlaceTaskbarLayout: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ApplyReorderTaskbarLayout: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsEmpty: HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  // Windows Vista
  IPinnedList = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{C3C6EB6D-C837-4EAE-B172-5FEC52A2A4FD}']
    function EnumObjects: HRESULT; stdcall;   // $18
    function Modify: HRESULT; stdcall;        // $20
    function GetChangeCount: HRESULT; stdcall;// $28
    function IsPinnable: HRESULT; stdcall;    // $30
    function Resolve: HRESULT; stdcall;       // $38
    function IsPinned: HRESULT; stdcall;      // $40
  end;

  // Windows 7, 8, 8.1
  IPinnedList2 = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{BBD20037-BC0E-42F1-913F-E2936BB0EA0C}']
    function EnumObjects: HRESULT; stdcall;   // $18
    function Modify: HRESULT; stdcall;        // $20
    function GetChangeCount: HRESULT; stdcall;// $28
    function GetPinnableInfo: HRESULT; stdcall;// $30
    function IsPinnable: HRESULT; stdcall;    // $38
    function Resolve: HRESULT; stdcall;       // $40
    function IsPinned: HRESULT; stdcall;      // $48
    function GetPinnedItem: HRESULT; stdcall; // $50
    function GetAppIDForPinnedItem: HRESULT; stdcall; // $58
    function ItemChangeNotify: HRESULT; stdcall; // $60
    function UpdateForRemovedItemsAsNecessary: HRESULT; stdcall; // $68
  end;

  // Windows 10 build 1809+
  IPinnedList3 = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{0DD79AE2-D156-45D4-9EEB-3B549769E940}']
    function EnumObjects(var ppv: IEnumFullIDList): HRESULT; stdcall;   // $18
    function GetPinnableInfo(ido: IDataObject; pinnableFlag: Integer; var isi, isi2: IShellItem; var us: USHORT; i: integer): HRESULT; stdcall;// $20
    function IsPinnable(pn: IDataObject; pinableFlag: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;    // $28
    function Resolve(hWnd: HWND; l: ULONG; pidl: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; var pidlo: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE): HRESULT; stdcall;       // $30
    function LegacyModify(unpin: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; pin: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE): HRESULT; stdcall; // $38
    //Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Taskband", L"FavoritesChanges
    function GetChangeCount(var FavoritesChanges: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;// $40
    function IsPinned(pin: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE): HRESULT; stdcall; // $48 S_OK = pinned S_FALSE = not pinned
    function GetPinnedItem(pidl: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; var pidlI: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE): HRESULT; stdcall; // $50
    function GetAppIDForPinnedItem(pidl: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; var apID: USHORT): HRESULT; stdcall; // $58
    function ItemChangeNotify(pidl1: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; pidl2: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE): HRESULT; stdcall; // $60
    function UpdateForRemovedItemsAsNecessary: HRESULT; stdcall; // $68
    function PinShellLink(us: USHORT; var ish: IShellLinkW): HRESULT; stdcall; // $70
    function GetPinnedItemForAppID(apID: USHORT; var pidl: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE): HRESULT; stdcall; // $78
    function Modify(unpin: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; pin: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE; caller: PLMC): HRESULT; stdcall; // $80
  end;

  LPNOTIFYITEM = ^tagNOTIFYITEM;
  tagNOTIFYITEM = record
    pszExeName: LPWSTR;
    pszIconText: LPWSTR;
    hIcon: HICON;
    hWnd: HWND;
    dwUserPref: DWORD;
    uID: UINT;
    guitItem: TGUID;
  end;
  NOTIFYITEM = tagNOTIFYITEM;


  INotificationCB = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_INotificationCB]
    function Notify(dwMessage: DWORD; var pNotifyItem: NotifyItem): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  ITrayNotify = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_ITrayNotify]
    function RegisterCallback(var pNotifyCB: INotificationCB): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPreference(pNotifyItem: LPNOTIFYITEM): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function EnableAutoTray(bTraySetting: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  { interface IShellDispatch6 Windows 8+ }
  IShellDispatch6 = interface(IShellDispatch5)
    [SID_IShellDispatch6]
    function SearchCommand: HRESULT; stdcall; { [helpstring] }
  end;

type
  TOnTaskbarPinChange = procedure(Sender: TObject) of Object;

  TTaskbarPinner = class (TObject)
  private
    FOnTaskbarPinChange: TOnTaskbarPinChange;
    procedure SetOnTaskbarPinChange(const Value: TOnTaskbarPinChange);
    function GetPinnedList: TStrings;
  public

  published
    property OnTaskbarPinChange: TOnTaskbarPinChange read FOnTaskbarPinChange write SetOnTaskbarPinChange;
    property Items: TStrings read GetPinnedList;
  end;

implementation

{ TTaskbarPinner }

function TTaskbarPinner.GetPinnedList: TStrings;
begin

end;

procedure TTaskbarPinner.SetOnTaskbarPinChange(
  const Value: TOnTaskbarPinChange);
begin
  FOnTaskbarPinChange := Value;
end;

end.

Using IPinnedList3 Modify will pin it or unpin it.
procedure TForm2.btnPinUnpinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  hr: HRESULT;
  pl: IPinnedList3;
  pidl: PItemIDList; // PItemIDList = PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE
  buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of WideChar;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);

  hr := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbandPin, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IPinnedList3, pl);
  if Succeeded(hr) then
  begin
    StringToWideChar(ParamStr(0), buffer, (High(buffer) - Low(buffer)+1));
    pidl := ILCreateFromPath(@buffer);

    hr := pl.IsPinned(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE(pidl));
    if hr = S_OK then // is already pinned, let's unpin
      hr := pl.Modify(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE(pidl), nil, PLMC_EXPLORER)
    else // this is the undocumented call to pin the pidl
      hr := pl.Modify(nil, PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE(pidl), PLMC_EXPLORER);
    OleCheck(hr);

    ILFree(pidl);
  end;

  CoUninitialize;
end;

If you want the "complete" demo experiment, here https://github.com/vhanla/DelphiExperiments/blob/main/VCL/Undocumented/Pin2Taskbar/TaskbarPinner.pas
But keep in mind, that it still needs to check Windows versions, maybe update IDL changes, handling the async answer for the new permission prompt, etc.
